# Better Way to Write This: SELECT * with COUNT > 1

Tags: sql, group-by, count, teradata

Anyone have any ideas as to how I can better write this piece of code?

```
SELECT Column_A, Column_B, Column_C, Column_D, Column_E
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE Column_A IN
 (
  SELECT Column_A
  FROM 
    (
     SELECT Column_A, COUNT(DISTINCT COLUMN_B) AS Column_B_Count
     FROM TABLE_A
     GROUP by Column_A
     HAVING Column_B_Count > 1
    ) AS A
 )
GROUP BY Column_A, Column_B, Column_C, Column_D, Column_E;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Any time you `GROUP BY` every column you select you really meant `DISTINCT` instead, although at 5 columns it starts to look suspicious.  You can put aggregate functions (like `COUNT`) after the `HAVING` clause, which means you can remove it from the `SELECT` list and get rid of the middle subquery.  Other than that, we need more info about your table/data.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    A.Column_A
    , A.Column_B
    , A.Column_C
    , A.Column_D
    , A.Column_E
FROM
    TABLE_A AS A
    JOIN
        (
            SELECT Column_A
            FROM TABLE_A
            GROUP by Column_A
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT COLUMN_B) > 1
        ) AS Column_B_Count
    ON A.Column_A = Column_B_Count.Column_A
```

Comment: Technically, no, since the outermost `GROUP BY` in the original would remove any duplicates (although at 5 columns I'm a bit suspicious myself).

Comment: `, COUNT(DISTINCT COLUMN_B) AS Column_B_Count` can be omitted if you just use `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT COLUMN_B) > 1` instead of referencing by that column alias in the `having` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Distinct Column_A, 
       Column_B, 
       Column_C, 
       Column_D, 
       Column_E
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE Column_A IN 
    (
     SELECT Column_A
     FROM TABLE_A
     GROUP by Column_A
     HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT COLUMN_B) > 1
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use window functions.  I think this is what you want:

```
select . . .
from (select a.*,
             min(column_b) over (partition by a) as min_b,
             max(column_b) over (partition by a) as max_b,
      from table_a a
     ) a
where min_b <> max_b;
```

You may still need the `select distinct`, if this query could return duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT -- same as the final GROUP BY of original query
   Column_A, Column_B, Column_C, Column_D, Column_E
FROM TABLE_A
  -- 
GROUP BY Column_A, Column_B, Column_C, Column_D, Column_E
QUALIFY -- emulating DISTINCT > 1, which is not allowed in Windowed Aggregates:
   MIN(COLUMN_B) OVER (PARTITION BY Column_A) 
<> MAX(COLUMN_B) OVER (PARTITION BY Column_A)
```

Depending on the actual data, i.e. a low number of duplicates per group, it might be more efficient to remove the `GROUP BY`.